# localhost htdocs folder locking, is it possible?

Tags: php, apache, locking, localhost, htdocs

I'm using my pc as a localhost point of sale for my small business, so placing my php files in htdocs or www ( for wamp ) folder is not safe, and can be accessed by any user.
I've tried doing folder locking by doing right click -> security tab but apache end up having troubles accessing the files.

I'm not that php expert but is it possible to lock those files, please help me !

Thank You

Comment: Simple .. use Client - Server Architecture that what the best is all about ... Don't use the same system for client and server ... there would always be an easy work around

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Apache..
This can come handy 
        http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/password-protect-folders-in-seconds/

Comment: Well ,I'm not looking for password protect via web browser, i would do it with php session and login.  I want to hide or lock the folder from the root C:/wamp/www folder. But thanks for your help!